# WCF structure with MessageContract and DataContract does't work

Tags: .net, wcf, datacontract, messagecontract

I have a WCF web service with multiple own datatype. This structure doesn’t work. I can call the WSDL, but if I try to call the method it throw the Exception:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://adress.
>   This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP
>   protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being
>   aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down).

I had read this article [WCF Web Service error: "Service endpoint binding not using HTTP protocol"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310369/wcf-web-service-error-service-endpoint-binding-not-using-http-protocol), but I don’t found my solution. I search for not set DataMember and I tried to set `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength..>` in the web.config, but this doesn’t change anything. What is wrong with my structure?

```
<ServiceContract(Name:="service", Namespace:="http://namespace")>
Public Interface IService1

   <OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://namespace/methodRequest", name:="method", ReplyAction:="http://namespace/methodResponse")> _
    Function method(input As methodRequest) As methodResponse
End Interface

<MessageContract()>
Public Class methodResponse

    Public result As Object

    <MessageBodyMember(Name:="return", Namespace:="")> 
    Public Property resultP() As Object
        Get
            Return Me.result
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            Me.result = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

<DataContract()>
Public Class typeArray

    Public typeArrayD As ownType()    

    <DataMember(Name:="value", Order:=1)>
    Public Property value() As ownType()

        Get
            Return typeArrayD
        End Get

        Set(value As ownType ())
            typeArrayD = value
        End Set

    End Property

End Class

<DataContract()>
Public Class ownType
    Private stringValueD As String    

    <DataMember(Name:="stringValue", Order:=1)>
    Public Property stringValue() As String

        Get
            Return stringValueD
        End Get

        Set(value As String)
            stringValueD= value
        End Set

    End Property
End Class

<ServiceBehavior(Namespace:="http://namespace", Name:="service")>
Public Class Service1
    Implements IService1

        Public Function method(input As methodRequest) As methodResponse Implements IService1.method

            Dim result As New methodResponse()
            result.result = New typeArray
            result.result.value = valueOfOwnType

            Return result
     End Function
 End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I must add the ServiceKnownType to the class. With this it works

```
<ServiceContract(Name:="service", Namespace:="http://namespace")>
<ServiceKnownType(GetType(typeArray))>
<ServiceKnownType(GetType(ownType))>
Public Interface IService1
...
End Interface
```